# Returning a new ArrayList, the list that is being returned is populated but still gives a null pointer exception

Tags: unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito, powermockito

I am writing a JUnit test case for a method that leads me to another method that is default, it returns a new ArrayList when that default method is called.

Test method

```
public List getTagDataForImage(String tagType, String imageType) {
        List tagRules = getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(tagType, imageType);
        List tagData = getTagData(tagRules);
        return tagData;
    }
```

In the method the stack trace points me to `getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(tagType, imageType);` which leads me here

```
List getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(String tagType, String imageType) {
        List commonList = tagList.getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(tagType
                + "," + imageTypes[0]); //This line 
        commonList.addAll(tagList.getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(tagType
                + "," + imageType));
        return commonList;
    }
```

definition for `tagList.getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(tagType
                    + "," + imageTypes[0]);` defined in another class

```
List getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(String tagType) {
        return new ArrayList((List) tagRulesMap.get(tagType));//gives NPE
    }
```

`tagRulesMap` is a HashMap that is populated automatically at constructor call

Test case

```
@InjectMocks 
    TagDataFilter tagDataFilter;
    @Test
        public void testGetTagDataForImage()
        {
            List get=tagDataFilter.getTagDataForImage("QueryImages", "Common");
        }
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at data.TagList.getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(TagList.java:107)
    at data.TagDataFilter.getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(TagDataFilter.java:92)
    at data.TagDataFilter.getTagDataForImage(TagDataFilter.java:73)
    at data.test.TagDataFilterTest.testGetTagDataForImage(TagDataFilterTest.java:54)
```

I am not able to figure out where I have gone wrong.Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Is your mock TagDataFilter not calling the real constructor?

Comment: Yes its is calling the real constructor

Comment: How do you mock the tagList dependency?

Comment: I have not mocked it, as the constructor of tagList is automatically called when I call the constructor of the test class.

Comment: Is it because tagRulesMap.get() searches for a value that doesn't exists and returns null in that case, after returning null it tries to cast to list ?

Comment: Yes I just printed it out and it printed null, But when I debug `tagRulesaMap` holds about 18 values. So the list is not empty.

Comment: Does it contain the a value for the key you are searching for? ArrayList.get returns null if the value for the passed key is not found...

Comment: It worked now, Like you said, I was passing the wrong key. the value is referenced from an xml file based on the key I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide a answer from the comments:

```
List getTagRulesForUpdateOrQueryImage(String tagType) {
    return new ArrayList((List) tagRulesMap.get(tagType));//gives NPE
}
```

the key tagType is not found and because of this it returns null which is then tried to cast which then returns a NullPointerException.